# ¿Como insertar datos con PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, formularios

A través de un formulario necesito definir un objeto de la clase `Persona` y llamar a sus métodos.
También crear un objeto de la clase `Empleado` y llamar a sus métodos
Esta información debo almacenarla en una base de datos.

Muchas gracias por la colaboracion!!!

Este es mi codigo

```
<?php

class Persona
{
    public $nombre;
    public $genero;
    public $edad;

    public function __construct($nombre, $genero, $edad)
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
        $this->genero = $genero;
        $this->edad   = $edad;
    }

    public function imprimeDatos()
    {
        return "Mi nombre es: {$this->nombre}, mi género es {$this->genero} y mi edad es: {$this->edad}";
    }

}

class Empleado extends Persona
{
    public function __construct($nombre, $genero, $edad, $sueldo, $tipoContrato)
    {
        parent::__construct($nombre, $genero, $edad);
        $this->sueldo = $sueldo;
        $this->tipoContrato = $tipoContrato;
    }

    public function cargaSueldo()
    {
        return "Tu sueldo ahora será de: $".$this->sueldo = $this->sueldo + 20;
    }

    public function tipoContrato()
    {
        return "Tu tipo de contrato es: {$this->tipoContrato}";
    }
}

$empleadoRoberto = new Empleado("Roberto", "Masculino", 23, 3500, "de por vida");
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $empleadoRoberto->imprimeDatos();
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $empleadoRoberto->cargaSueldo();
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $empleadoRoberto->tipoContrato();
```

Esta es mi DB

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema o error o dificultad en lo que estás intentando?

Comment: Necesit mediante POST enviar datos de un formulario, y que se guarden en una sede de datos